# How to use `evaluate` after `fit` with `validation_split` parameter?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am using Keras to perform some ANN training.
At some point, I am using `model.fit()` on a [Sequential](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) model and I use the `validation_split` parameter, e.g.:

```
model.fit(..., validation_split=0.3)
```

Then, I would like to use `model.evaluate()` on the validation data as produced by `validation_split`.
Is there a way to do so? Or do I have to just forget about `validation_split`, perform the splitting *manually* and the validation likewise?

Comment: I would split before. I don't think you can access the same data afterwards. Try using https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html or something similar

Comment: But `model.evaluate` will give you exactly the same results you got in training.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about `validation_split`, perform the splitting using `sklearn`.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=[X_val, y_val])
```

Comment: Why? What benefits does this give? Cheers

Comment: Maybe you want to change `random_state` to debug your model's behaviour for different orders.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate validation data on the end of each validation step (e.g epoch). To have control over metrics you can use `keras.callbacks.Callback` and Tensorboard.

If you really want to use evaluate() on validation data then splitting before fit is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
train_eval = model.evaluate(x_train[:int(len(x_train)*(1-validation_split)-1)], y_train[:int(len(y_train)*(1-validation_split)-1)]) val_eval = model.evaluate(x_train[int(len(x_train)*(1-validation_split)-1):], y_train[int(len(x_train)*(1-validation_split)-1):])
```

Comment: Kindly add enough details to your answer so that it can be understood by future readers.